# List, метод remove() баг в языке Java или миф?

Tags: java, list, коллекции, arraylist

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Soffi");
        list.add("Kate");
        list.add("Mimo");
        list.add("Mike");
        System.out.println(list);
        list.remove(1);
        list.remove(3);
    }
}
```

У нас 4 элемента: 
Подсчёт по индексу: 0 1 2 3 (4 элемента)
А мне выдает ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:535)
    at Example.main(Example.java:12)
```

Неправильно походу работает что ли?))

Comment: было 4 элемента, стало 3

Comment: Не называйте свои вопросы как темы сочинений. SO - это база данных знаний. Представьте, что вы хотите задать свой вопрос в гугле(и кстати лучше гуглить сначала свой вопрос) - вот такой заголовок и делайте. Например для этого вопроса - не `List, метод remove() баг в языке Java или миф?`, а `Почему при удалении элемента из листа remove() выходит исключение?`

Comment: Эх. Мне бы самооценку как у людей, которые задают вопросы а ля «баг в языке». Это же насколько надо быть уверенным в своей правоте... даже нет... в своей **гениальности**, чтобы в случае выброса ошибки винить не *себя/свои руки/свою логику*, а сам **язык**!

Comment: @Kir_Antipov с сарказмом у вас всё плохо к сожалению

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван: видимо по той причине, что сарказма в моем сообщении и не было ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Kir_Antipov -_-, я вообще-то про свой

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас был лист с индексами от 0 до 3. Вы удалили элемент(`remove(1)`), их стало на 1 меньше, лист перестроился в лист с индексами от 0 до 2. После этого вы хотите удалить элемент с индексом 3(`remove(3)`), а у вас уже нет такого индекса.

Answer (score 1):

Напишите `list.remove(2);` и посмотрите, что выйдет.
В ArrayList при вызове `remove()` ячейка удаляется из массива со смещением всех элементов к началу. Чтобы оставить по индексу пустое значение, нужно использовать `list.set(2, null);`